# Differential Op-Amp rising and falling error at zero

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

So I have a differential OP-AMP I've designed is essentially a cut and paste of the circuit seen below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvqcrW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm using it to track the difference between the output of two Trans-impedance amplifiers.   the circuit works well as long as there is a difference between signals, but as the signal difference approaches zero I have an error I cant fix. it occurs on the rising and falling edges of the signals and I believe it may be due to slight differences in response times from the photo-diodes because when I recreate the signals using a function generator the error goes away.  How would you compensate for something like this or am I incorrect in thinking its due to differences in response times in each photo-diode?

for reference here is the error that I'm seeing on a scope the first two signals represent the output of my trans-impedance amplifier, the third is the error I see as the difference approaches zero.

[image: Error as difference approaches zero]

Comment: It's unlikely to be the problem, but OP27's really aren't cut out for 100 ohm loads. Try a 1k to 10k instead.

Comment: Disclose the transimpedance amplifier situation, as well. Also, what have you done to remove unintended influences (optical) up to the point where the intended light reaches the photodiodes? Your "noise" (3rd trace) signal shows evidence of correlation with the transition edges. I doubt that is desired.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. A straightened up look at the scope shows the sensitivity settings for each channel.*

Your Channel 3 sensitivity is 20 times that of the other channels. It seems to me that the noise is about 1/40 that of the signal.

> How would you compensate for something like this or am I incorrect in thinking its due to differences in response times in each photo-diode?

I'm not sure why you'd compensate. That's the actual error. You've proved it with the signal generator.

Comment: Thanks, yes I should have specified it is a small error, the reason why its significant is I want to measure the stability of a laser by pointing it at two diodes, the pulse width in practice will be 100ns so this error gives me a minimal precision that I can achieve to observe the wobble of the laser.  I was hoping I could compensate this to get even better resolution.

Comment: @FreezeSSC. You are complaining about a 2.5% noise error? Ok...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the noise is related to 5% of dV/dt rather than voltage or, time delay , phase difference.

dV/dt could be current noise, the result of square wave supply or ground  current shift.

Can you check?